# Function that returns the earliest time point when a worker is allowed to start duty

Tags: c, datetime

The task is to provide a function that returns the earliest time point when a worker is allowed to start duty.

The function uses two parameters:

- Time stamp when the rest starts
- The number of local nights which is necessary according to a table

I wonder if there is anything wrong with `void convertTimeStructToLocalTime(TimeStamp * const timeStructToConvert)` in the code. Is it OK to use constant pointer to the `TimeStamp` structure in `convertTimeStructToLocalTime`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//has tm_isdst flag to be used for daylight saving time
typedef struct tm TimeStamp;
typedef enum {false, true} bool;

TimeStamp getEndOfRest(TimeStamp startOfRest, int neededLocalNights);
bool isNeededLocalNightsInTheRange(int neededLocalNights);
void convertTimeStructToLocalTime(TimeStamp * const timeStructToConvert);

//to make tests easier
void wrapGetEndOfRest(TimeStamp startOfRest, int neededLocalNights);

int main(void) {
    int y=2016, m=2, d=27;
    int y2=2016, m2=12, d2=28;
    int daysDelta = 0;

    TimeStamp t = { .tm_year=y-1900, .tm_mon=m-1, .tm_mday=d, .tm_hour=12, .tm_min=5, .tm_sec=10 };
    TimeStamp t2 = { .tm_year=y2-1900, .tm_mon=m2-1, .tm_mday=d2, .tm_hour=9, .tm_min=59, .tm_sec=5};

    //tests
    for(daysDelta = -1; daysDelta < 8; daysDelta++){
        convertTimeStructToLocalTime(&t);
        printf("%s is the start add %d days\n", asctime(&t), daysDelta);
        wrapGetEndOfRest(t, daysDelta);
    }

    for(daysDelta = -1; daysDelta < 8; daysDelta++){
        convertTimeStructToLocalTime(&t2);
        printf("%s is the start add %d days\n", asctime(&t2), daysDelta);
        wrapGetEndOfRest(t2, daysDelta);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


//Since the minimum for neededLocalNights is 2 according to the table the time of departure is always 6 am
TimeStamp getEndOfRest(TimeStamp startOfRest, int neededLocalNights){
    startOfRest.tm_mday += neededLocalNights;
    startOfRest.tm_hour = 6;
    startOfRest.tm_min = 0;
    startOfRest.tm_sec = 0;
    convertTimeStructToLocalTime(&startOfRest);
    return startOfRest;
}

bool isNeededLocalNightsInTheRange(int neededLocalNights){
    if(2 <= neededLocalNights && neededLocalNights <= 5){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

void convertTimeStructToLocalTime(TimeStamp * const timeStructToConvert){
    int ret = mktime(timeStructToConvert);
    if( ret == -1 ){
        printf("Error: unable to make time using mktime\n");
    }
}

void wrapGetEndOfRest(TimeStamp startOfRest, int neededLocalNights){
    if(isNeededLocalNightsInTheRange(neededLocalNights)){
        startOfRest = getEndOfRest(startOfRest, neededLocalNights);
        printf("%s is the end\n\n", asctime(&startOfRest));
    }
    else{
        printf("Error: the neededLocalNights is out of range min 2, max 5 got: %d \n\n", neededLocalNights);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Why not just use [`<stdbool.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html) instead of defining your own `enum` for it?  If it has to do with the standard being used, then make sure you're compiling under C99 or GNU99.
- It looks like `t` and `t2` are for testing and more could be added at some point.  If so, you could have an array of `TimeStamp`s to help make the code more concise.
- `isNeededLocalNightsInTheRange()` can be simplified as such:

  ```
  return 2 <= neededLocalNights && neededLocalNights <= 5;
  ```

  This will automatically return the appropriate condition.
- Try to avoid magic numbers by instead making them into constants.  This would apply to the `2`, `8`, `6`, `5`, and `0` (the `-1` indicates an error and doesn't apply here).  Comments aren't always helpful enough and don't explain each of these anyway.
- Error messages should be printed to [`fprintf()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm) with its first argument as `stderr` to indicate this.  `printf` only prints to standard output.